# Creating a dictionary where the values are methods

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a System.Collections.Generic.List of the files what I'm getting from 7z.
For each of these files I need to write some sort of parser to process them and get useful information.

Maximum number of the files is 21.

So logic is:
I have a dictionary:

```
{
    Dictionary<string, string> filestoproces = new Dictionary<string, string>(21);
    stfiles.Add(appevent.evt, applicproc);
    stfiles.Add(codes.txt, codesproc);
    stfiles.Add(cpu_info.htm, cpuinfoproc);
    stfiles.Add(drives_defrag_info.txt, ddefragproc);
    stfiles.Add(DxDiag.txt, dxdiagproc);
    stfiles.Add(sysevents.evt, syseventproc);
}

Directory.GetFiles
S:\test_project_st\test\appevent.evt
S:\test_project_st\test\codes.txt
S:\test_project_st\test\cpu_info.htm
S:\test_project_st\test\drives_defrag_info.txt
S:\test_project_st\test\DxDiag.txt
S:\test_project_st\test\sysevents.evt
```

Maybe you can offer something more compatible for this task.
The idea is to parse files from the list...

The question is can I use somehow method in value of the key using Dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have dictionary with values of type `Func<T>` or `Action<T>`, depending on what is this processing that you do for each item. For example, if each processing function should return void and take a single string parameter, you could use `Action<string>` delegate as your values type and initialize dictionary like this

```
Dictionary<string, Action<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>(21);
```

Then you would define delegates for your each processing function and add them to dictionary with appropriate filenames as keys.

There's more useful info on [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) delegates from MSDN.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer.
I cannot vote for your answer yet, sorry... :(
I will check this information! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

C# supports [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), which are basically pointers to functions or methods.  There are a number of generic delegates built in to .NET that can support any<sup>1</sup> method signature.  The simplest of these is [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx), which represents a method that takes no parameters and returns no value.  This type can be used for the values of your dictionary.

Here's a simplified example of creating a dictionary with Actions and then invoking each of them:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, Action> files = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    files.Add("file1", MethodForFile1);
    files.Add("file2", MethodForFile2);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Action method = file.Value;
        method();
    }
}

private static void MethodForFile1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processing file 1.");
}

private static void MethodForFile2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processing file 2.");
}
```

If you need a different signature (like one that takes parameters) there are other delegate types like `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` that can be used instead.

---

<sup>1 Well, every signature that has 16 or fewer parameters.  If you need more than that, you have bigger problems.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer.
I cannot vote for your answer yet, sorry... :(
I will check this information! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry BJ I will check Antonia's answer as a right. She(he) is also newbie :) Thank you anyway!

Comment: Very appreciate example! Thank you~